# Pthread condvar idiom

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

I'm curious whether anyone has used something like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point_mutex);

while(!ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point)
  pthread_cond_wait(&ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point_cv, &ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point_mutex);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point_mutex);
```

... when waiting on a condvar.

The idea is that the `feeder_safe_point` `int` variable will be set to `1` when the event is completed and then the waiting thread will be woken up.

Also, what is the recommended way to use condvars to serialise the execution of multiple threads

Comment: Looks good to me. Assuming all variables are declared as implied by their names and also had been initialised properly.

Comment: Any comments regarding the performance of this? Can it be optimised?

Comment: As `pthread_cond_wait()` is doing nothing, I do not really know what to optimise here. The only to case where optimsation might be necessary would be if you experience a whole lot of (spourious?) wake-ups of `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is exactly how you should use a pthreads condition variable.  `ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point` should also only be modified with `ctx->processing_pipeline.feeder_safe_point_mutex` locked.

Comment: And what if feeder_safe_point is being only manipulate trhough some sort of atomic-guaranteeing functions. In my particular case I'm using glib so I can use g_atomic_int_set/get? The thing is there are only one place where I need to use this waiting idiom, but several more where I have to just modifying it atomically, and holding a mutex each and every time seems a bit of an overkill?

Comment: @LordDoskias: It doesn't matter - you still need to lock the mutex around the modification because you need the test (in the `while()` loop condition) and the call to `pthread_cond_wait()` to be atomic with respect to modification of the variable.